# Add Tripadvisor Review as Rich Snippet

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, rich-snippets, review

I've read a bit about rich snippets and I'm interested in the reviews part.

Is there a way to add the TripAdvisor aggregate reviews dynamically as a rich snippet without "hard-coding" the number of stars and a review?

From what I've read rich snippets are not dynamic, so I can't add a link or a tag for example, that would automatically just load my star ratings and the text of the latest review (just like a widget would do).
Is there?

The site is created in `Joomla` and I've installed `J4Schema` to add rich snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.
Rich snippets are currently a "manual thing". Meaning that you will insert them by hand in your code, and you can reference TripAdvisor externally, but this will not create a link to the TripAdvisor account.

Google, at some point (in my case, after 6-8 months) will process these rich snippets, and will show them for the search result in question.

Also, a periodic update of these snippets is to be maintained to insure relevance.